# android recording a landscape video in a portrait activity

Tags: android, video, android-camera, orientation

I have set up everything and it's working.

- portrait activity
- landscape preview

  ```
  <Framelayout
  android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
  android:layout_width="720px"
  android:layout_height="480px"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
  ```

the preview orientation is also good(no stretching when oriented)
However, when I eventually save the video, it's recording half of a portrait.

this is what it looks like
[image: this is what it looks like]

this is the video it saves
[image: this is the video it saves.]

How can I save a landscape video with a landscape video preview in a portrait activity?

In other words, how can I take the video as I see it in the preview? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution to this currently.

You cannot take a landscape video if you're holding your phone in portrait.
You just can't.